# Altering a QUALIFY with an additional criterion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

In Snowflake I have this original query which, for a given consumer_ID, produces a list of unique store IDs.

```
SELECT
t.consumer_id
, t.business_id
, t.store_id
, t.campaign_id

FROM campaigns_mini AS t

QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.consumer_id, t.store_id ORDER BY t.campaign_id) = 1
```

The original purpose was to provide a list that does not duplicate store_id for a given consumer_id.  Suppose now I also need to ensure this list does not duplicate business_id as well for a given consumer_ID.  Is there an easy way to modify the above?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
t.consumer_id
, t.business_id
, t.store_id
, t.campaign_id
FROM campaigns_mini AS t
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY t.consumer_id
                 ,t.store_id
                 ,t.business_id
     ORDER BY t.campaign_id) = 1
```

The partition by clause forms windows by the combination of all the expressions in the clause.

This will deduplicate by the combination of consumer_id, store_id, and business_id. If this is not what you need, please update with sample input and output to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

So if I make up some data:

```
WITH campaigns_mini(consumer_id, business_id, store_id, campaign_id) as (
    select * from values
    (1,10,100,1000),
    (1,10,100,1001),
    (1,10,101,1002),
    (2,20,200,2000)
)
```

and use your exist SQL

```
SELECT
    t.consumer_id
    ,t.business_id
    ,t.store_id
    ,t.campaign_id
FROM campaigns_mini AS t
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.consumer_id, t.store_id ORDER BY t.campaign_id) = 1
```

I get

| CONSUMER_ID | BUSINESS_ID | STORE_ID | CAMPAIGN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 101 | 1002 |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| 2 | 20 | 200 | 2000 |

we get the Store not repeated for the Consumer, but as you note you don't want the business repeated ether..

If we change to using `business_id` instead of `store_id` we see we get less rows:

```
SELECT
    t.consumer_id
    ,t.business_id
    ,t.store_id
    ,t.campaign_id
FROM campaigns_mini AS t
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.consumer_id, t.business_id ORDER BY t.campaign_id) = 1 
ORDER BY 1;
```

| CONSUMER_ID | BUSINESS_ID | STORE_ID | CAMPAIGN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| 2 | 20 | 200 | 2000 |

So if we want "no repeating business_id AND no repeating stores" using the Qualify Greg's has proposed will not help, as we are keeping the first for the distinct set of consumer,business, & store:

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.consumer_id, t.business_id, t.store_id ORDER BY t.campaign_id) = 1
```

which gives:

CONSUMER_ID |BUSINESS_ID    |STORE_ID   |CAMPAIGN_ID
1   |10 |100    |1000
1   |10 |101    |1002
2   |20 |200    |2000

So the next thing is to think why not keep the only the first of the two sets:

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.consumer_id, t.store_id ORDER BY t.campaign_id) = 1 
   AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.consumer_id, t.business_id ORDER BY t.campaign_id) = 1
```

which for this data works!

| CONSUMER_ID | BUSINESS_ID | STORE_ID | CAMPAIGN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| 2 | 20 | 200 | 2000 |

but then for this data:

```
WITH campaigns_mini(consumer_id, business_id, store_id, campaign_id) as (
    select * from values
    (1,10,100,1000),
    (1,10,101,1001),
    (1,20,101,1002)
)
```

there is only one row with business 20, for store 101, but the first 101 store is on campaign 1001, so both those rows are discarded.

| CONSUMER_ID | BUSINESS_ID | STORE_ID | CAMPAIGN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |

So if we use two layers to do the prune, for this data:

```
select * from (
SELECT
    t.consumer_id
    ,t.business_id
    ,t.store_id
    ,t.campaign_id
FROM campaigns_mini AS t
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.consumer_id, t.business_id ORDER BY t.campaign_id) = 1
) 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY consumer_id, store_id ORDER BY campaign_id) = 1
```

works:

| CONSUMER_ID | BUSINESS_ID | STORE_ID | CAMPAIGN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| 1 | 20 | 101 | 1002 |

but if your flip those orders of QUALIFY you are back to just one row..

so as a general problem it cannot be safely solve for all data cases with this pattern...